# Python pandas big DataFrame deleting empty columns/rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with a huge DataFrame. I need to clean it, but just the rows, where from -1 to 2 the Amount and the Bill a zero (see picture)
Maybe it ist possible to connect the rows and after that delete it, but I do not know how?

[image]

Thank you Hanna

Comment: Can you post that same sample as text into your post, and does the 0 value you want to remove always come after -1?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a simplification of the data frame so I do not have it as text. But yes the 0 always comes after the -1

Comment: If you aren't providing any sample data then you're expecting people here to recreate your data manually and provide an answer? You won't get any decent answers and most likely will get downvoted read [mcve]

Comment: For sure it was my fault, I will try to create it. But I am new and not so good in it, so very often the things does not work

Comment: No worries, don't take down votes too personally. You can just select the data in your excel and paste it here as text, it's not so difficult to re-create it as dataframe from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try selecting the index of rows and apply drop method.

```
temp_df = df[(df.Delivery > -2) & (df.Delivery < 3) & (df.Bill == 0)]
index_lst = temp_df.index.values.tolist()
df = df.drop(index_lst)
```

Comment: Here it shows a invalid syntax for "] " is there a mistake ?

Comment: Ok now it works. But in my DataFrame are NaN and not zeros. I did it wrong in the excel. Do you know how to call them for this part     (df["Bill"] == 0), instead of the "0" ?

Comment: Try the following:
(df["Bill"].isnull())

Answer (score 0):

I your looking to exclude all data where *Delivery* is between *-1* and *2*, and *Amount* is *0*, you can filter your DataFrame:

### Short Answer

```python
df = df[df["Delivery"].isin(range(-1,3)) & (df["Amount"] == 0)]
```

---

### Long Answer

#### Create a DataFrame example

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Delivery": [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 2], "Amount": [2500, 2500, 2500, 3500, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

```
   Delivery  Amount
0        -1    2500
1         0    2500
2         1    2500
3         2    3500
4        -1       0
5         0       0
6         1       0
7         2       0
```

#### What is a filter?

A filter is a Series that contains the values `True` or `False` for each row in a Pandas DataFrame or Series.

For example, a filter to give us the *first*, the *second* and the *last* row of the DataFrame given in the example would look like this:

```python
f = pd.Series([True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True])

df = df[f]
```

```
   Delivery  Amount
0        -1    2500
1         0    2500
7         2       0
```

#### First Filter:  *Delivery* is between *-1* and *2*

```python
f1 = df["Delivery"].isin(range(-1, 3))
```

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
```

#### Second Filter: *Amount* is *0*

```python
f2 = (df["Amount"] == 0)
```

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
```

#### Connecting both filters with *AND*

```python
f = f1 & f2
```

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
```

#### Finally, apply the filter

```python
df = df[f]
```

```
   Delivery  Amount
4        -1       0
5         0       0
6         1       0
7         2       0
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, can I delete the rows with zero from the dataframe with dropna or something like this?

Comment: You can just use `df = df[df["Amount"] != 0]` if you want to delete all rows where Amount is 0.

Comment: oh yes that i it thank you. Do you know how it works with empty rows, because I showed it wrong in the excel. So in the Column of "Bill" is not a number and not a 0 ?

Comment: That would be `df = df[~df["Amount"].isna()]`

Comment: There comes this message: TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool] Can you help ?

Comment: @Hanna We're all here to help, but before asking others please give yourself some time and (1) try to debug errors on your own and (2) use the forum search.

Comment: Yes, I will make:)